# SpringDoc Maven Plugin to generate OpenAPI

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin

Trying to generate OpenAPI documentation using the springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin.

https://springdoc.org/#plugins

I added the springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin configuration exactly as suggested in the documentation.
I already had the spring-boot-maven-plugin configures, and I also added the goals start/stop as suggested in the https://springdoc.org/#plugins

Running `mvn verify` fails

```
[INFO] --- springdoc-openapi:1.4:generate (integration-test) @ my-application ---
[ERROR] An error has occured
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0 (Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect (DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:75)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:476)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:218)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect (PlainSocketImpl.java:162)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect (SocksSocketImpl.java:394)
    at java.net.Socket.connect (Socket.java:606)
    at java.net.Socket.connect (Socket.java:555)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect (NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer (HttpClient.java:499)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer (HttpClient.java:594)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init> (HttpClient.java:278)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New (HttpClient.java:375)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New (HttpClient.java:393)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient (HttpURLConnection.java:1240)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0 (HttpURLConnection.java:1167)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect (HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect (HttpURLConnection.java:995)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0 (HttpURLConnection.java:1584)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream (HttpURLConnection.java:1512)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode (HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at org.springdoc.maven.plugin.SpringDocMojo.execute (SpringDocMojo.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:910)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:52)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:73)
```

Comment: What is the url of your application? Just default localhost:8080 or different?

Comment: the application is running on localhost:8303
The springdoc is running on localhost:8080

Comment: Start application manually and check if you can access http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs/

Comment: This is the default url used by the plugin to generate file.